# Can't delete font even from registry WINDOWS 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, fonts

I have the usual problem that prevents me from deleting fonts saying that the font is in use.

I tried everything and nothing happens, and this time searching the font in the registry I can't even find it.

Comment: What error do you get if you try and delete the .ttf from %windir%\fonts?

Comment: It tells me that the file is in use even if I have all apps closed

Comment: In that case if you're desperate to delete the file, F8 on boot up to bring up the boot menu, then drop into a command prompt. Delete, reboot and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue this week and fixed it by downloading Microsoft's [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and going to Find > Find Handle or DLL... (Ctrl + F) and searching for the font. It will show you what app is using it and you can then kill the app and will be able to delete the font.